# Deploying Rails app over VPN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

You'll have to bear with me as I'm not a Ruby dev, but have inherited a Ruby system.

I need to deploy some changes to the app from my repository to the server.  I've been instructed to run `cap deploy` and told that that script will get the latest code from my repository and deploy it to the server.

My problem is that I have to VPN to get to the production server and the VPN client then blocks access to my local network, cutting off the repository.  So my question is, how can I change my `deploy.rb` so that I can deploy from my local machine instead?  Or is there a better way.

If you need to see the `deploy.rb`, please let me know.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've used before means adding:

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

However, it may be better to read more about this at:

http://www.capify.org/index.php/Understanding_Deployment_Strategies#Deploy_Strategy_:copy

Comment: Be aware that :copy behaves differnetly to the others, and will deploy whatever is active on your workstation at the time, which might have horrible consequences. The page Seb linked says it all, however Capistrano has great support over at google groups.

Comment: It looks like :copy will have to do for the time being, but we are looking into getting split tunnelling working with the VPN to allow Capistrano to talk to both the repos and the server.  Thanks for your replies!